# Only the main calendar from my Google Account syncs to the Calendar app

Tags: google-calendar, windows-8

I have a Google Account with two calendars:
[image: Multiple Google Account calendars]

In the Calendar app that comes with Windows, only the default one (Louis) syncs.

I've tried to check the settings on https://m.google.com/sync/settings/iconfig/ (I believe you can spoof your browser to an iOS device to see this page correctly) but the calendars don't appear where they normally would (for an iOS, or Windows Phone device for example).

How can I sync the second calendar?

Comment: See http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-winapps/shared-google-calender-doesnt-show-up-in-calendar/dc12618b-ca22-4398-84fb-5828b2118f0b?msgId=9931659e-85c4-4d33-948a-520ea3487b49

Comment: @Ihavethesameproblem thanks, can you make an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone posted a working solution on [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-winapps/how-to-sync-multiple-gmail-calendars-using-the/3c0bc19a-c991-424a-ab00-039a318136d2):

1. Download [User Agent Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lkmofgnohbedopheiphabfhfjgkhfcgf) from the Chrome Webstore
2. Select an iOS device
3. Go to http://m.google.com/sync
4. Deactivate Javascript in Settings (`Show advanced settings`, `Content settings`)
5. Click your Windows Mail device
6. In the URL change `supportMultipleCalendars=false` to `supportMultipleCalendars=true`
7. Save
8. Readd your Google Account to your Windows Calendar app. It now works.

Answer (score -1):

I saw another working solution here.

http://mashtips.com/google-secondary-calendar-windows8

Comment: Please quote the bulk of the answer here, rather than just providing an external link.