# How do I sync multiple g-calendars to the new Windows 8 Calendar?

Tags: sync, google-calendar, windows-8, windows-8-calendar-app

I'm able to add multiple g-calendars from multiple accounts, but it appears that only the root calendar is synced with Windows 8's Metro Calendar app.  Is there a way to sync all gmail calendars?

Comment: It might not be possible.  You could try adding the other calendars on a single calendar, that should depending on the share settings of the other calendars, do what you want.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From a [question I asked](https://superuser.com/questions/462365/only-the-main-calendar-from-my-google-account-syncs-to-the-calendar-app/468374#468374):

Someone posted a working solution on [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-winapps/how-to-sync-multiple-gmail-calendars-using-the/3c0bc19a-c991-424a-ab00-039a318136d2):

1. Download [User Agent Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lkmofgnohbedopheiphabfhfjgkhfcgf) from the Chrome Webstore
2. Select an iOS device
3. Go to https://m.google.com/sync/settings/iconfig/welcome?source=mobileproducts
4. Deactivate Javascript in Settings (`Show advanced settings`, `Privacy` > `Content settings` > `Do not allow any site to run JavaScript`)
5. Click your Windows Mail device
6. In the URL change `supportMultiCalendars=false` to `supportMultiCalendars=true`
7. Submit URL (Press Enter)
8. Check the boxes for the calendars you'd like to sync
9. Save
10. Readd your Google Account to your Windows Calendar app. It now works.
11. (Re-enable JavaScript in Chrome)

Comment: Went through these steps and it didn't work.

Comment: Strange, it works for me and at least 5 others. I wonder if the Google Calendar people caught on.

Comment: BTW, in between steps 6 and 7 you would have to select the extra calendars.

Comment: I was able to select the different calendars, but they still don't show up on the calendar app.

Comment: It took a little while, but it eventually worked!  Great find.

Comment: Strange, not working for me. I can see the other calendars on my Windows Phone but not on Windows 8.

Comment: Step 4 is not detailed enough for casual chrome users. I'd add some more detail to it, eg: Deactivate JavaScript in Settings (SELECT Chrome Menu on the Menu Bar, SELECT Settings..., CLICK Show advanced settings, (In the Privacy section) CLICK Content Settings..., (In the JavaScript section) SELECT Do not allow any site to run JavaScript. Also, It may not be obvious to the reader that this is a Chrome browser specific instruction set.

Comment: Works for me, done with Firefox

Comment: This is brilliant, worked perfectly for me!

Comment: The initial sync afterward is slow, but this does work just fine.

Comment: Note that you don't have to delete and add your entire account again, you can just uncheck calendar sync, go to the main menu (so it saves), then check calendar sync again

Comment: It appears google has broken this somehow. I could only do this by going to m.google.com/sync on an iPhone and disabling javascript in Safari. Didn't work in Chrome or IE spoofing the user agent string

Answer (score 10):

At the moment, this probably can't be achieved.  This same Question has been asked on [MS Support](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_cp-winapps/syncing-multiple-google-calendars-with-new-ui/b87f68b7-8bd8-4327-a87b-4d10c7f6bf89) and they have replied with a no.

**Question**

`Syncing Multiple Google calendars with New UI Calendar app`

**Answer**

> Currently per Google's request for bandwith, Calendar App only Sync
>   root calendar.
>
> Developers on both sides are working on this issue to improve
>   accessibility on this.

Another thread from the [Ms Support](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-winapps/how-to-sync-multiple-gmail-calendars-using-the/3c0bc19a-c991-424a-ab00-039a318136d2)

**Question**

> How to sync multiple Gmail Calendars using the Mail, Calendar, Messaging and People App?

**Answer**

> You have multiple calendars in your Gmail calendar but only one of
>   them syncs with the Calendar app and you want to know how to sync all
>   the others calendars to the Calendar app. Please note that currently
>   per Google's request for bandwidth, Calendar App will only Sync root
>   calendar. Developers on both sides are working on this issue to
>   improve accessibility on this.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest fix is just to import each Google Calendar into a hotmail account.  Then when you add this account to the Windows 8 Calendar app not only do they all appear, but they are still organized by color.

Comment: If the Google Calendar is modified are the changes reflected by the Hotmail account?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have changed again:

1. Using [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome), ensure you are [signed in to Google](https://accounts.google.com)
2. Add [User-Agent Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lkmofgnohbedopheiphabfhfjgkhfcgf) from the Chrome Web Store
3. From the face icon that appears in the toolbar select iPhone
4. Go to https://m.google.com/sync
5. All of your devices should now appear (Windows 8 is known as **WindowsMail**)

Comment: That url gives me Not Found

Error 404

Comment: @OmarShahine - Which url exactly.  They all worked for me.