# How to show subscribed Gmail calendars in Windows 8 calendar app

Tags: windows-8, google-calendar

Is it possible to show my subscribed calendars on Gmail in the Windows 8 calendar app like I'm used to do on my Windows Phone?

I think - but am not sure about that - that it uses the mobile API. When I try to configure it via http://m.google.com/sync on my Windows Phone I can see the client "WindowsMail" but cannot add or configure shared calendars as for my smartphone.

Is there currently a possibility to achieve this or do we need to wait until they get that enabled for us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously I just didn't find this answer: [How do I sync multiple g-calendars to the new Windows 8 Calendar?](https://superuser.com/questions/464453/how-do-i-sync-multiple-g-calendars-to-the-new-windows-8-calendar)

Trust me, I searched for it, but I didn't find this.

The solution in the link above worked for me.