# Can I manually force the Windows 8 calendar app to sync?

Tags: calendar, windows-8, windows-8-calendar-app

I have an Exchange Server (2003) account which I access through a variety of means, one of them being the Windows 8 calendar app. I added an appointment to my calendar through my iPhone, which has successfully been synced to the Exchange Server (i.e. it shows up in Outlook Web Access).

However, the appointment is not yet shown in Windows 8 calendar, although all other appointments are shown. I have tried to find a "sync" button in the calendar app (like the one in the mail app), but there does not seem to be one.

How can I manually trigger synchronization with the server?

Comment: Are you using [multiple calendars](http://superuser.com/questions/462365/only-the-main-calendar-from-my-google-account-syncs-to-the-calendar-app/468374#468374)?

Comment: @Louis: No, I'm only using one Exchange Server account (plus the mandatory Microsoft account, which I don't use but which gets added anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Syncing the mail app also causes the calendar to be synced.** (At least when using an Exchange Server backend, don't know about others.)

In my case, it appears that the synchronization thread somehow got stuck, which is why the new appointment never showed up. (An error message would have been helpful...) Playing around with the account settings and rebooting the system eventually fixed it.